# SQL Where on different table

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * FROM student_mentor sm INNER JOIN users u 
  ON sm.student_id = u.user_id 
  WHERE sm.teacher_id = $teacher_id
```

Teacher_id being the session id,

I want to see all the students that have the same mentor.
Right now if I run this I just see all of the students twice, maybe one of you knows why?

[My db scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21NpX.png)

Comment: please read this before posting https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It does run https://gyazo.com/e0d50fa3e97c4eac9bf2ac6be4e5deee

Comment: there is no join condition between your tables! why do you need the users table?

Comment: @EstebanP. I did read that actually, what's the issue?

Comment: Could you show us what your tables look like and what is expected output? Please read also [mcve]

Comment: @MarekVitek https://gyazo.com/3b609a2b28d9f574ffb494e2ee706df6 that's what my tables look like. Then the output expected is a fetchall statement that gives me all the user rows that have a mentor with the teacher_id that is in the session

Comment: And what you get when running simply `SELECT * FROM student_mentor WHERE teacher_id = $teacher_id` Does it also return duplicate values?

Comment: @MarekVitek Yes that works, but the issue is that I want the rows from the user where the user_id = student_id from that result

Comment: I know that. I am jut trying to eliminate possible places where you can get duplicates since you claim that what Nir Levy wote doesn|t work. Can you also try to run `SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $id_of_one_of_duplicate_students`

Comment: @MarekVitek I think there is an issue in my php code tbh. It works if I run it in phpmyadmin. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Well you know where to look now. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying on which columns you want to do the join, so you're getting a cross reference where all records are joined to all records.

You should do something like (not sure about your column names):

```
SELECT * FROM student_mentor sm INNER JOIN users u 
  ON sm.student_id = u.user_id 
  WHERE sm.teacher_id = $teacher_id
```

Comment: You just updated with ALMOST same query See the difference between INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN